# Is the Riemann sphere complex manifold with boundary?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-geometry

Can anybody help me? I know that, Is  the riemannian sphere complex manifold with boundary and is compact complex manifold?

Answer (score 1):

The Riemann sphere is indeed a compact complex manifold but it does not have boundary if that's what you are asking. It's the compactification of the complex plane. You can look at it as taking a closed ball in the complex plane and contracting its boudary to a single point obtaining a compact manifold with no boundary. In the book "introduction to general topology " by Sze-tsen Hu, the compatification is well explained. The stereographic projections give you parametrisations of the riemann sphere.

The definition of a manifold with boundary is an hausdorff topological space with countable basis which is locally homeomorphic to $\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_n \geq 0\}$

Comment: I would note that the term "manifold with boundary" usually allows the boundary to be empty, so the Riemann sphere would still be a complex manifold with boundary.

Comment: What is the definition of a complex manifold with boundary?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1957840/what-is-the-definition-of-a-complex-manifold-with-boundary

Comment: yes, I ment the boundary is empty, but usually we say that a manifold has a boundary if it has a non-empty boundary